# Iconsets paths in 2SXC

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Is possible to use the font icon picker in a regular content template? I only got it to work inside 2SXC Apps but not inside regular Token Content. All examples I found where using the [App:Path] token to load the iconset. For regular Content Templates as there is no AppPath I tried [Portal:HomeDirectory] but I can't get it to load the icons. Is it limited to be used in Apps?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[App.Path] and @App.Path should also work on content templates, it's certainly not disabled on purpose. The path will always point to the Portals/x/2sxc/Content, so you can also hardwire it - but it should work.

Comment: perfect, then you should close this question :)